# Same 'find' query in loopback and mongo has different behaviors in different servers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopback

I am trying to make a query in a loopback model JS file. It is very simple and it as follow:

```
    //isAdmin function: gets a boolean if a given userProfileId is an admin or not.
    Userprofile.isAdmin = function(userProfileId, cb) {
        let role = app.models.Role;
        let rolemapping = app.models.RoleMapping;

        let filter = {
            "where": {
                "name": "admin"
            },
            "fields": ["id"]
        };

        role.findOne(filter, function(err, instance) {
            let filter2 = {
                "where": {
                    "roleId": instance.id
                    ,
                    "principalId": userProfileId,
                },
                "fields": ["id"]
            };

            rolemapping.find(filter2, function(err, instance) {
                if (instance != "") {
                    cb(null, true);
                } else {
                    cb(null, false);
                }
            });
        });
    };
```

This works perfectly in our development server. The `console.log` of `filter2`, in that server returns:

```
{ where: 
    { roleId: 5890ef8bbef9b73e568c6933,
        principalId: '5890ef8bbef9b73e568c6932' },
        fields: [ 'id' ] 
    }
 }
```

The `console.log` of `instance.id` looks like:

```
ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'Xï¾ù·>Vi3 }
```

The issue is in our production server. I have made the deployment process and the result is slightly different, but it does not work at all :(.

The `console.log` of `filter2` returns:

```
{ where: 
     { roleId: 58921dff16d9a37009e21104,
          principalId: '5890ef8bbef9b73e568c6932' },
          fields: [ 'id' ] }
}
```

And, `console.log(instance.id)` returns:

```
ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: Buffer [ 88, 146, 29, 255, 22, 217, 163, 112, 9, 226, 17, 4 ] }
```

This query in our production server does not return any documents, even if there are documents in the DB that satisfy the query.

I have compared all the npm packages, and all are exactly the same version. As well the servers (we are using Debian 8) and mongo (v3.2.10).

Does any have an idea to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Pedro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced a similar issue when querying with an ID of a related model. Solved the issue by opting for like instead of equivalence like below:

```
{where: 
   {and:[{roleId: {like:'.*'+roleIdVar+'*.', options:'i'}},
      {principalId: {like:'.*'+principalIdVar+'*.', options:'i'}}]
   }
 },
 {fields: [ 'id' ] }
```

Please also note that field projection should be a separate object from the where filter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the userProfile id type in the "userProfile".json file? That seems a ids type problem. You could solve it adding in the properties the id with type string, in your model.json file, something like this:

```
"properties": {
"userProfileId": {
  "type": "string"
}
```